# Does nature have a mechanism to turn charcoal back to usable carbon?

Tags: biochemistry, ecosystem

I have in past [asked this about ash](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/81445/6918), but apart from ash most fires - whether natural or fires in stoves - leave a bunch of charcoal as well. When I was sifting old compost last year, I could identify the layers where the fire pit contents were dumped in - but not by ash, as it really mostly dissolved and disappeared, but by charcoal (and also nails sadly).

In those layers, there were chunks of charcoal as well as larger partly decomposed pieces of wood covered by charcoal.

So, since no wildfire is perfect to the point of burning all organic matter perfectly, what happens to the charcoal after wildfires - or to the charcoal that is dumped with ashes to composts and gardens? Carbon is extremely chemically stable unless you set it on fire, so is there anything that can oxidize it in nature?

If not, is the soil in places of common wildfires rich in pure carbon crystals from millennia of fires and regrowth?

Comment: https://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/51463/20220620/430-million-year-old-charcoal-deposits-oldest-wildfires.htm, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1871174X20300172, https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.energyfuels.1c01559. I would suggest researching "biochar".

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - not really. Charcoal as almost pure carbon is fairly inert, not readily available and can remain in the environment almost indefinitely. This is evidenced by [charcoal in rocks](https://time.com/5295907/discover-fire/) from the [Silurian period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silurian) (~440 million years ago). We also find evidence of forest fires in the form of charcoal in almost all time periods since this point.

I've personally picked charcoal out of buried soils that is at about 2000 years old from [volcanic eruptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatepe_eruption) - admittedly there the top layers might well have been sterilized by the heat of the pyroclastic flows, so not a perfect analogy.

However we can identify domestic camp sites from Neanderthal and other early human species for the past ~160,000 years, mostly from ash and charcoal presence.

Edited to add: in the case of biochar and similar products, the charcoal is used to act as a reservoir for the nutrients (charcoal is really good at absorbing things *a la* [activated charcoal](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/322609#_noHeaderPrefixedContent)), which can be taken up into the microstructure of the charcoal and released as the plant rootlets and/or [mycorrhizae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhiza) invade. The charcoal also provides a looseness to the soil allowing greater aeration, better drainage and allowing roots to penetrate to a greater depth. These all help plants to grow well.